# WKWebView instead of UIWebView - Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, uiwebview

New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability.

This is the issue I am facing when developed the App in IONIC and trying to upload the app to appstore.

Comment: What version of Ionic, Cordova/Capacitor are you using? And What Plugins are you using? some plugin are too old to use and they uses `UIWebView`. upgrade your project and use Latest version og Plugins.

Comment: Are you using InAppBrowser, if yes then please update the plugin to latest compatible version

Comment: @HarshitRastogi we are not using InAppBrowser

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Ionic Version: 6.17.0     Cordova Version:  10.0.0  We tried to remove all the plugins but camera plugins which we using (cordova-plugin-camera) is mandatory for the app and it is not upgrading and still showing UIWebView

Answer (score 0):

Add plugin `cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine`, preferably the latest version

Make sure you have this in your config.xml and

```
<platform name="ios">
  <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
  <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
  </feature>
  <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
</platform>
```

Comment: We tried to implement these but the issue remains.